# How can I put my old Lumia 730 which has a bad sd card slot to good use

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-730

I have used my WP a lot, now it's in a deteriorating state, my family considers it electronic waste and wants me to throw it away, but I have an emotional attachment to the phone, any ideas to how can I put the phone to some productive use.